# Properties of unitary representations for projective representations

Tags: representation-theory, ergodic-theory, mixing, representation-of-algebras

I would like to know if there exist concepts of ergodicity and mixing properties for projective representations. If they do, do these properties exhibit similar characteristics to those observed in the context of unitary representations?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know what ergodicity and mixing mean in this context, but projective representations of a group $G$ correspond to actual representations of a suitable extension of $G$, so anything you know about actual representations can be applied.

Comment: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Projective_representation lists a paper by Mackey; which might be a good place to reference chase.